# Whitespace appearing inside the DIV

Tags: html, css

I am very new to CSS. I am creating a DIV and somehow the text is being displayed in middle of the DIV. There is a white-space appearing above the first line of the text.
I am also providing the CSS that I wrote for this DIV.

CSS Code

```
#CONTAINER {

   float: left;
   height: auto;
   padding-top: 0;
   border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;

 }

#CONTAINER  p {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
vertical-align: top;


 }
```

Here is the Link to the page. Please refer to the last Div which says Latest News
[enter link description here][1]

Comment: In addition to posting your markup, you can make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: `vertical-align` won't work on this CSS unless you set `display: table-cell;`

Comment: Please note that [linking to your website without all relevant code in your question is bad practice](http://tinyurl.com/so-debug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your "Latest news block," there is an h2 element outside of the div that your text is in that is pushing everything down.

```
<div id="block-nodeblock-21" class="block block-nodeblock">

    <h2>Latest News Block</h2> <!----this guy-->
    <div class="content">
```

The element is invisible because you set `visibility:hidden`, however this does not remove it from the page, so it still affects the position of everything around it. To make it truly hidden, you can

- Remove it OR
- Set `display: none;`

Comment: Note that the `h2` has `visibility: hidden;`. This will make the content of the element invisible, but *will not remove it from layout*. This causes the element to still take up the space it normally takes up with all of its margin/padding/etc. The `h2` either needs to be removed, or set to `display: none;`.

Comment: Please advise what should be the CSS for rectifying it. Thanks

Comment: @user3527763 See my comment just above yours.

Comment: @user3527763 As @ajp said, use `display:none` or take it out entirely

Answer (score 0):

First off we need your HTML that goes with it, however also remember that the P tag has got its own whitespace added by default, try - values for your padding under

```
#CONTAINER p
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, that outside the div, you have set the "text-align" property to the value "center". Out of interest, does this occur in any other browsers?